# Distinct on only one column

Tags: sql, distinct

I would like to only get the distinct Accounts using SQL management studio

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Account]
  ,[Opportunity Name]
  ,[LeadContact Email]
  ,[LeadContact Name]
  ,[LeadContact Status]
FROM NAME
 WHERE [Account Addr Country] LIKE '%US%'
 AND [LeadContact Name] NOT LIKE '%Test%'
ORDER BY [Account]
```

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you are using.  Also, you mention a count in your title but your query does not attempt to count.  What are you counting?

Comment: Distinct works per row.

Comment: If you have two rows with the same `[Account]` but different everything else, which of the two rows should the query return? After answering this question, the rest will be easy.

Comment: What output do you want if an account has multiple opportunities and.or leads?  A random one?  Is there a programmatic way to choose the desired one?

Comment: There are two different tasks matching your description: *either* you want to pick one row per account and show this (then you'd have to tell us how to decide for a row) *or* you want an aggregation per account and show, say, its minimum status, its last email in the alphabet, a string containing all opportunity names comma-separated or the like (in which case you'd have to tell us what aggregations you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT Account, [Opportunity Name], [LeadContact Email],
      [LeadContact Name], [LeadContact Status]
FROM (SELECT n.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY Account) as seqnum
      FROM NAME n
      WHERE [Account Addr Country] LIKE '%US%' AND
            [LeadContact Name] NOT LIKE '%Test%'
     ) n
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This selects one indeterminate row.  If you want a specific row (such as the earliest or latest or biggest or smallest), you can adjust the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you!! Gordon Linoff :) amazing my friend.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, the easiest way to do this is the following request :

```
    SELECT 
     [Account]
     ,[Opportunity Name]
     ,[LeadContact Email]
     ,[LeadContact Name]
     ,[LeadContact Status]
    FROM NAME n inner join (
      SELECT distinct [Account] FROM NAME 
      WHERE [Account Addr Country] LIKE '%US%'
      AND [LeadContact Name] NOT LIKE '%Test%' ORDER BY [Account]) n2
    on n.Account = n2.account
```

The first inner request retrieves all distinct accounts and the second one retrieves the complementary informations

Comment: An inner join will return duplicates if there are multiple matching records, so your query will not return "distinct" accounts.